# Skype for 32 bit

Tags: skype

I just did a fresh install of ubuntu and I wanted to install some additional software to it. I did a 32 bit install of ubuntu desktop and I realised that **skype does not support 32 bit version anymore**. I tried to install manually some older versions of skype but none of them seemed to work. I just wanted to ask if **is there a way to get skype up and running on a 32 bit system at the current time**. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The current version - the only one that works -  is 64-bit only. Install a 64-bit OS if your hardware is 64-bit.

Comment: No man i have a 32 bit operating system,isn't there any way to get it on 32 bit?

Comment: @KnownAsDon has 32 bit computer, right?

Comment: *i have a 32 bit operating system* No doubt. The point is: Do you really need a 32-bit OS? You do if your hardware is 32-bit. Otherwise install a 64-bit OS and any software you want.

Comment: You mean to get my operating system to 64 bit?

Comment: Cause i have an hardware comatible for both 64 bit and 32 bit

Comment: If your hardware is compatible with 64 bits, then ubuntu 64 bits will be better for you.

Comment: @VitorAbella im afraid that it will make my pc slower(i have really old processor and no graphic card)

Comment: @KnownAsDon so follow my answer, it may work. The second method is the one I believe is likely to work.

Comment: @VitorAbella ok so now i should make a bootable ubuntu 64 bit usb and install it on my pc?

Comment: @KnownAsDon wherever you search on google, ubuntu 64 bits is better than 32 bits. So I suggest you to install 64 bits with a bootable flash drive.

Comment: @VitorAbella Thank You so much man i really apprushiate your help(if i spelled that rifght) thank youu man :))))))

Comment: @KnownAsDon you are welcome. Please, edit your question, delete your history life and let only what matters. One guy with no 64 bits option may need a good answer.

Comment: @VitorAbella do you have a kik or something where we can talk cause id really need some advice from a pro like you man.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay guys so for my answer i have a good news and a bad one.The bad one is that the only way to run skype on ubuntu linux is to have a 64 bit proccesor.The good news is that most of you guys have a 32 bit pc but that is compatible with 64 bit as well,if not i am sorry for you but dont lose hope cause im pretty sure skype is coming with many new updates in the near future and i am pretty sure that 32 bit based operating system skype is one of them.

Comment: What makes you so sure that Microsoft will release Skype for 32-bit Linux? Linux is already a niche market for desktop computing and 32-bit installations are another niche among current Linux desktop installations, so that would be a niche within a niche. There’s really no good reason to run a Linux desktop installation for 32-bit CPUs these days; if your hardware is incompatible with 64-bit instruction sets it’s quite old and probably not powerful enough to run the new Skype client anyway.